# Add x-axis including tickmarks at 0 with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a chart with data going below and above 0, and I want to have my x-axis with tick marks at y==0, while tick labels are still below the chart. Note that using `axhline` is not sufficient as I need tick marks. Also, there are workarounds on SO that use `spines` to put the top spine at 0, with tick marks, but in my case I would need to keep the spines add the top and bottom.

Is there a way to do this?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(-2, 3))
plt.show()
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(-2, 3))
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.yaxis.tick_left()
ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(-0.1,0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately I need to keep my spines at the top and bottom for formatting purposes.